# RabbitMQ Message size limit (string)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rabbitmq

I installed RabbitMQ on Ubuntu 16.04 and installed management plugin. Now trying to publish a data to queue. Data is in json format and contains 2000 + lines. When i paste in publish message space i can see full data is there, after publishing when i try to get message only half of the json is there in message.

Size of the actual json is 60K and the data i get from get message is 52K. Is there any limit in RabbitMQ or Operating System Level ?

```
{running_applications,
     [{rabbitmq_management,"RabbitMQ Management Console","3.5.7"},
      {rabbitmq_web_dispatch,"RabbitMQ Web Dispatcher","3.5.7"},
      {webmachine,"webmachine","1.10.3-rmq3.5.7-gite9359c7"},
      {mochiweb,"MochiMedia Web Server","2.7.0-rmq3.5.7-git680dba8"},
      {rabbitmq_management_agent,"RabbitMQ Management Agent","3.5.7"},
      {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.5.7"},
      {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.4"},
      {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.5.7"},
      {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.10"},
      {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","6.2"},
      {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.13.3"},
      {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.7"},
      {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.8"},
      {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","4.2"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,
     "Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:64] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
```

Comment: What have you set as your queue limit? https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html

Comment: Tried giving 10 MB , still same

Comment: I'm assuming that "When i paste in publish message space i can see full data is there..." means that you are using the management UI to publish your message. You should write a real application to publish your data and check that.

Comment: In addition, RabbitMQ 3.5.7 and Erlang 18 are both very, very out of date and out of support.